# AddressSanitizier: error: undefined reference to "__asan_report_load4"

Tags: android, c, linux, clang++

When I compiled a test Android program by enabling the AddressSanitizier, I got this error:

```
error: undefined reference to __asan_report_load4
```

Does anyone know what happened here?

This is my Android.mk：

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := asan_boom.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libc

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O1 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer

LOCAL_MODULE := asan_boom

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

Comment: please provide build/linker command line

Comment: make asan_boom LOCAL_SANITIZE:=address LOCAL_CLANG:=true LOCAL_ADDRESS_SANITIZER:=true -j16           ("asan_boom" is my test program)

Comment: ok, can you put them in your question, along with the contents of the makefile?